# google-data-studio merge summarized data with raw data

Tags: looker-studio

I'm using google data studio + google sheets as data source and would like to merge my summarized data with my raw data. My raw Data Looks like this:

job-name | start-date | end-date | produced-quantity | runtime | job-type

I aggregated my fields by job type with blended data and obtained this:

job-type | average-runtime | median-produced-quantity

Right now i would like to link my summarized data back to raw data to have something like:

job-name | start-date | end-date | produced-quantity | runtime | job-type | **median-produced-quantity**

How could I do this ? I want to avoid calculations inside google sheets and keep everything inside GDS. I tried blending data raw data twice, but it's not working and I can not blend my raw data with already blended dataset. What approach should I take? I will be grateful for any advice

Kind regards,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine a dataset with itself.

Add your dataset twice to the blend. Put the field `job-type` to the Join keys. On the left dataset fill all dimensions and metrics. On the right dataset include your two caluclated fields `average-runtime` and `median-produced-quantity`

[image]